# Access to Facebook?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook

As a little learning project, I'd like to make a little app that reads data from a facebook users status updates. It's been done millions of times before, I'm sure, but is there an API or something? Would I need to signup for some Facebook developers license or anything, or is it as easy as finding the API, and then simply coding to it?

I'd like to simply get friends Status Updates via my login... seems easy enough. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Facebook Developer links posted above are good, but it might be useful to look at some examples.

The Facebook C# SDK, found here: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/, has samples in ASP.NET MVC. It's a pretty simple project, so it should be relatively easy to see how things work in practice.

You can create an app at http://developers.facebook.com/

Then, download the sample project, replace the AppId and AppSecret with values from your registered app, and see how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can start reading here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/

And look in the forum discussions here: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/index.php

Answer (score 1):

This post was helpful to me http://gathadams.com/2007/06/18/how-to-write-a-facebook-application-in-10-minutes/

Also keep in mind this last change made for FB team about Post for canvas http://developers.facebook.com/docs/canvas/post/

Good luck!